# Scrolling slides with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 4 divs inline, using php I assign an unique id for each of those, at any momment just one div is visible, this is the result html:

```
<div id="contentslider">
    <div class="cs_wrapper">
        <div class="cs_slider">
            <div id="1" class="cs_article">
                SLIDE 1
            </div>
            <div id="2" class="cs_article">
                SLIDE 2
            </div>
            <div id="3" class="cs_article">
                SLIDE 3
            </div>
            <div id="4" class="cs_article">
                SLIDE 4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.contentslider {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  width:480px;
  height:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.cs_wrapper {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  width:480px;
  height:400px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.cs_slider {
  position:absolute;
  width:10000px;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.cs_article {
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display:block;
  width:480px;
  height:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
}
```

Im trying to code a jquery function that given an id it will animate and go to the selected slide but I have no idea where to begin, any suggestions?

**EDIT**: Heres a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kMnsZ/) if you need it.

Comment: I dint know that, buy i can easily correct that on PHP, thanks!

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There are dozens of existing jquery slideshows out there.

Comment: Just so you know, an ID or a class cannot just be a number or start with a number. You could try deconstructing Bootstrap's Carousel to see how they made that: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a quick [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTDL3/1/) with the function.  As the comment above on your question, I changed the IDs to non-numbers.

Here is the function:

```
function GoToSlide(id) {
    $(".cs_article:visible").slideUp("slow");
    $("#" + id).slideDown("slow");
}
```

Comment: This works great! but i wonder how can i create also a button to go next o back?

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent tutorial by Martin Angelov on creating a very similar application to what you are describing: [Beautiful Apple-style Slideshow Gallery With CSS & jQuery](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/11/beautiful-apple-gallery-slideshow/)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer hide-all approach.

This is to navigate slides with arrow keys without using your css.

```
$(".cs_article").hide();
$(".cs_article").eq(0).show();
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    curSlide = $(".cs_slider .cs_article:visible");
    if (e.which==37 &&  curSlide.prev()[0]) { 
        curSlide.hide(); curSlide.prev().show();
    } else if (e.which==39 && curSlide.next()[0]) {
        curSlide.hide(); curSlide.next().show();
    }
})
```

If you want to show one, just show one

```
$(".cs_article").hide();
$("#3.cs_article").show();  // to show slide 3 only
```